# org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is not resolved in tycho build

Tags: eclipse, maven, tycho

I have a project which builds and runs fine when built with eclipse, but when I trz to build it with maven & tycho, I get

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
```

The bundle is indeed in the plugin directory, and referenced by config.ini.

What is the problem, and how to solve it?

You can find the code here:
https://github.com/magwas/archi/tree/48c26595a87ddcfff994e3b9b058b6d6ad30f61e

This is the full error report:

```
!SESSION 2014-05-02 10:57:06.671 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-05-02 10:57:07.615
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-05-02 10:57:07.615
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.200.v20120913-144807 [46] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86 2 0 2014-05-02 10:57:07.615
!MESSAGE Platform filter did not match: (& (osgi.ws=gtk) (osgi.os=linux) (osgi.arch=x86))

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-05-02 10:57:07.615
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Comment: The 'Platform filter did not match' line seems to be saying you have an 'x86' launcher (32 bit) but you are running 'x86_64' (64 bit)

Comment: The product is compiled for both x86 and x86_64, and I am running it on x86_64, so not being able to resolve the x86 one gtk is fine, I guess.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Unable to acquire application service" error when starting an Eclipse application built with Tycho](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295890/unable-to-acquire-application-service-error-when-starting-an-eclipse-applicati)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is coming because you are not setting startup lavel for org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle.

Open your product and set start level as below image.

[image]

Comment: Would you please paste whole config.ini content here?